# What is a good design pattern for dealing with complex classes that have potential null sub classes?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5

I am using Entity Framework Model First to create a data access layer. In my MVC project I am using this DAL to retrieve a complex object from my DB.

```
var street2 = Person.Address.Street2;
```

What I am trying to determine is what pattern or process I should be using to handle potential situations where Street2 or even Address doesn't have a record in the DB.

I know I could test for null objects at the point where I am using them but I was wondering if there is a pattern or method that would remove the need to do that at such a fine grained level. i.e.

```
if(Person.Address!=null && Person.Address.Street2!=null)
{
var street2 = Person.Address.Street2;
}
```

Until we get a [Safe Navigation Operator](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator.aspx) is there another good pattern to use?

Would it make sense to create a getter in the classes to check for null objects and if there is create a new empty object and return that?

Am I making this more complex then it needs to be?

Any thoughts on AutoMapper and it's null substitution?

Comment: I think if you were making it more complex than it needs to be the upcoming navigation op wouldn't be one of the things _everyone_ seems to want.

Comment: You are making this more complex then it needs to be

Comment: Until Safe Navigation Operator is available you could use Monads - e.g. https://github.com/sergun/monads.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. That's the way you've to do it. You've to do it the way you're doing.

However use short circuit in your `if` conditions to increase performance

Comment: You are forced to use short circuit ops. Without it would result in NRE.

Comment: Yes I would use more efficient Ifs I was was trying to get some pseudo code in place to express my concept. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could create object validators and use [Decorator pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46029/data-validation-design-patterns)
this would work for updates and such, you still manually would have to check for nulls in places where logic demands.